# overriding zf2 modules configuration in phpunit test

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm trying to write a test for a module that requires a specific configuration change during a test run, overwriting the default configuration provided by the module's own `module.config.php`.

In a normal application run, configuration is merged in order and I can use `config/autoload/*.local.php` to supersede module's config. But during a phpunit run those files aren't loaded, and I can't find a way to modify it during testing runtime.

I tried modifying the config in my Bootstrap file, to no avail; and even in the test controller setup directly:

```
public function setUp()
{

    $app_config = include(Bootstrap::getRootPath() . '/config/application.config.php');
    $test_config = Bootstrap::getTestConfig();

    $new_config = ArrayUtils::merge($app_config, $test_config);

    $this->setApplicationConfig($new_config);

}
```

But by the time one of the factories is running I check the values for the config during a debug session, and my injected values are nowhere to be found.

Also tried hooking to `EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG` and modify it there:

```
public static function onMergeConfig(ModuleEvent $e)
{
    $configListener = $e->getConfigListener();
    $config = $configListener->getMergedConfig(false);

    $new_config = ArrayUtils::merge($config, $this->getTestConfig(static::$zf2ModulePaths));

    // Pass the changed configuration back to the listener:
    $configListener->setMergedConfig($new_config);
}
```

What's the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: How to you bootstrap the application in your unit-tests?

Comment: Bootstrap.php file included in my phpunit.xml file. Bootstrap runs normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I go with a similar approach as [zfcampus/zf-development-mode](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-development-mode) does. Depending on the environment, I add another `config_glob_paths` to the application configuration. While I use it for managing development related configuration, this can easily be adapted for testing.

The basic idea is to have two application configuration files, one general and one environment specific (expect for production).

`application.config.php`:

```
return [
    'modules' => [],
    'module_listener_options' => [
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            __DIR__ . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],
        'config_cache_enabled' => false,
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => false,
    ],
];
```

`development.config.php`:

```
return [
    'modules' => [],
    'module_listener_options' => [
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}-development.php',
        ],
        'config_cache_enabled' => false,
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => false,
    ],
];
```

Merging those two, will autoload the files matching in this order:

```
    'config_glob_paths' => [
        __DIR__ . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}-development.php',
    ],
```

While the later ones (postfixed with `-development`) will overwrite settings of the default ones.

So in my `autoload` directory I have the files like:

- `database.global.php`
- `database.global-development.php`

Local files are still possible for each environment as well of course:

- `database.local.php`
- `database.local-development.php`

The load order on development for the files then would be (if existing):

- `database.global.php`
- `database.local.php`
- `database.global-development.php`
- `database.local-development.php`

On a production environment, the `development.config.php` file is not merged, hence the `*-development.php` files are not loaded.

This pattern can easily be changed to testing environments as well of course. It is also noteworth that by this approach, you can change other application settings as well (e.g. application config caching / modules to load).